# Disagreeing with a failed review audit

Tags: support, review-audits

I failed this review audit right now: https://superuser.com/review/first-posts/271481

Why was this a bad answer? What they said seemed reasonable, and since I don't have the required knowledge to understand whether it was a correct or incorrect answer, I reviewed the post as "No action needed", since it *did* look like an answer.

Am I supposed to skip these kind of questions? Wasn't the point of reviewing to catch *bad* posts, like "not-answers" or SPAM?

Comment: That post is really not an answer. It's actually a question for more details. Even if it wasn't a question, it'd be quite brief.

Comment: I still think it *is* an answer: "If limit is 16GB, it's impossibile that mobo support over 16Gb". This answers the question of whether it is possible to have more than 16 GB in the NAS. It is definitely brief, yes, but it's still an answer, in my eyes.

Comment: A good answer should not contain questions to the author. A good answer should answer the question. A follow-up question indicates the author of the answer does not have a complete understanding of the question. Outside of that a single sentence isn't an answer in this case, I would normally would expect an answer to explain the reason 16GB is the hard limit **( sort of like how I indicated that exact fact ).**

Answer (score 6):

> since I don't have the required knowledge to understand whether it was a correct or incorrect answer, I reviewed the post as "No action needed", since it did look like an answee

There's this handy button called "skip".

[image]

use it if you don't know well enough whether it's a correct/incorrect answer. Don't review as "No action needed".

Comment: I know about that button, that's why I asked if I am supposed to skip these kind of questions :) the point of reviewing is to understand all the answers well enough to know whether they are correct? That seems too much for me, and probably means I may be doing it wrong. My reviews try to separate the garbage from the honest questions/answers. When I know the answer is wrong, I downvote and typically comment. When I see it is right, I upvote. When I don't know, but consider it to be a valid approach, I review as "No action needed". I only skip when it really is in a grey area IMO.

Comment: You can't understand every topic.  So unless you know the reason the hardware has a hard limit of 16GB you shouldn't say the answer is acceptable.  **The "comment" your asking about....I mean answer in this case wasn't acceptable.**  **It didn't explain the reason it wasn't possible.**